# color guessing game. How to stop the loop after guess is right

Tags: javascript

How to stop the loop after guess is right?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onLoad = "do_game()">
<script>
    var target;
    var color = ["blue", "cyan", "gray", "green", "magenta", "orange", "red", "white", "yellow"].sort();
    var guess_input_text;
    var guess_input;
    var finished = false;
    var guesses = 0;

    //main function
    function do_game() {

        var random_color = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)]; // Get a Random value from array
        target = random_color;
        while (!finished) {
            guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors:- \n\n" + 
                                       color.join(", ") + 
                                      ".\n\nWhat color am I thinking of?");
            guess_input = guess_input_text;
            guesses += 1;
            if( guess_input === target){
                alert("Your Guess is Right.Congratulations!");//finish which causing problem
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: break; after the alert statement

Answer (score 1):

If I didn't misunderstood your question, you want to stop it after you alert that the guess is correct.

Your loop is checking that `finished` is true or not, so your loop **will not** stop if `finished` is still false.

The solution is to set the `finished` to `true`. The following code should work:

```
function do_game() {
    var random_color = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)]; // Get a Random value from array
    target = random_color;
    while (!finished)
    {
        guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors:- \n\n" + 
                                       color.join(", ") + 
                                      ".\n\nWhat color am I thinking of?");
        guess_input = guess_input_text;
        guesses += 1;
        if( guess_input === target)
        {
            alert("Your Guess is Right.Congratulations!");
            finished = true;
            // You can also use break statement to
            // make sure that the loop will stop.
        } 
    }
}
```